# How to heal a callback channel?

Tags: .net, wcf, dispose

If a WCF channel is faulted we can dispose the current connection and reopen it. But if a callback connection drops, I can't see no way of healing it, except if the client pools the server constantly.

Is it possible to dispose and reopen a callback channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. You may have to prevent the channel from ending up in the Faulted state:

- All service exceptions must be wrapped into FaultExceptions (check the IErrorHandler interface) and properly handled on the client as well
- If the client channel is closed then there is nothing you can do about it.